# Generating PDF doc using asp.net for free while using form or HTML table

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I have a aspx page which is having a form. The form contains two HTML table. Some of the cells in these tables have specific style. What is the best way to convert these two table along with styles into a PDF document while using asp.net.

I have tried iTextsharp library and retaining CSS class is not easy while transforming HTML table into PDF.

Please suggest any library which is easy to use and can convert HTML table or form into PDF.

Comment: Why isn't "retaining CSS class" easy? Can you show sample code, basic HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I've not used those kind of libraries too much, so I can't suggest one, I'm afraid.

However, it depends on what you're trying to achieve, but it may be worth looking into SQL Server Reporting Services.  That'll be free if you've already got a SQL instance up and running.

You can create a 'report', which you can design as you like, load data into it, then render it out as a PDF document (or Excel, or an image, etc.).  That 'report' can match your form.

Yes, it will involve duplicating the design in two places, and it may be a little heavy, but I've found it to be the easiest way to export things consistently.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But I cannot use SSRS in my case. My application got a simple aspx page and that page got two table. I just want to render those table along with CSS class. Since I already I have table and CSS class ready, I am looking for simple solution utilizing these tables.

Answer (score 0):

ABCpdf .NET will do what you want.

It has an MHSTML engine for IE-like PDF output and also a Gecko engine for Firefox-like page output.

It is designed for real-world HTML pages and URLs so it doesn't need to be mollycoddled. Just give it the pages and let it work.

I work on ABCpdf so my replies may contain concepts based around it. It's what I know. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I don't want to write the entire page in PDF. My page have some headers, labels and 3 tables. I just want to write those 3 tables into PDF document. Also, I don't want to save this file physically on the server and would like to use memory stream as the volume of data that needs to be written on PDF is very small.